# How do you to get more than one <Configuration>\_PublishedWebsites from TFSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

The Configuration sections specify to do 2 Configuration Builds, but I only get the Release_PublishedWebsites generated by the TFSBuild.

Here are the configurations: (I started with two but actually will have 5)

...
    
            Release
            Any CPU

```
    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
        <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
        <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone that has figured this out!

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have post there is only 1 Configuration to build : Release|Any CPU.

Note in you example the configuration is "Release" and "Any CPU" is the platform you are building.

About your question, are you trying to build your project for Release and Debug for example?
If so, you could try something like that:

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
                <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
                <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Debug|Any CPU">
                <FlavorToBuild>Debug</FlavorToBuild>
                <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

In that code, we are including the Configurations Release and Debug to build for the platform Any CPU

Answer (score 1):

The problem was FlavorToBuild was incorrectly specified as Release in both ConfigurationToBuild Nodes.  This was the fix: (note  revised to Training from Release)

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Training |Any CPU">
        <FlavorToBuild>Training</FlavorToBuild>
        <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>

    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
        <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
        <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
</ItemGroup>
```